# Does Kotlin support or have future plan for Interface Composition similar to Protocol Composition in Swift?

Tags: swift, kotlin

The answer I found so far is probably a NO but I wonder if there is any plan of future support for this feature. Here is what it looks like in Swift.

> Protocol compositions have the form SomeProtocol & AnotherProtocol. You can list as many protocols as you need, separating them with ampersands (&). In addition to its list of protocols, a protocol composition can also contain one class type, which you can use to specify a required superclass.

```
protocol Named 
{
    var name: String { get }
}

protocol Aged 
{
    var age: Int { get }
}

func wishHappyBirthday(to celebrator: Named & Aged) 
{
    print("Happy birthday, \(celebrator.name), you're \(celebrator.age)!")
}
```

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm new to Kotlin and don't know Swift.  How is this different by having the two interfaces defined in Kotlin, and then defining "interface NamedAged : Named, Aged {}" ?

Comment: Firstly, the obvious benefit is that you don't pollute your namespace with filler interface NamedAged. Secondly, when you have an imported module that has class Foo which adopts Named and Aged but know nothing about the interface NamedAged you created in your own code. You could pass Foo object to function that require Named & Aged but impossible for those with NamedAged.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can not explicitly define intersection types in Kotlin, but you can use generic type constraints to achieve it in a function parameter. Like this:

```
interface Named {
    val name: String
}

interface Aged {
    val age: Int
}

fun <T> wishHappyBirthday(celebrator: T) where T : Named, T : Aged {
    println("Happy birthday, ${celebrator.name}, you're ${celebrator.age}!")
}
```

Comment: Also interesting.  I guess the difference between both of these and defining a combined interface is that the actual parameter object doesn't have to have implemented that interface necessarily...just the two explicitly required.  Yes?

Comment: @angtutheky, do you consider this equivalent?

Comment: @marstran: Thanks, this basically is the equivalence for Swift Protocol Composition.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin interfaces aren't quite the equivalent of Swift protocols :) In particular, interfaces can't be implemented conditionally or added as an extension. But there is ongoing work to [add type classes to Kotlin](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/pull/87) which would provide the missing capabilities. With them, you'd write

```
fun <T> wishHappyBirthday(celebrator: T, with Named<T>, with Aged<T>) {
    println("Happy birthday, ${celebrator.name}, you're ${celebrator.age}!")
}
```