# Typealias - Combine Multiple Interfaces in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm a bit rusty with protocol composition in Kotlin, I'd just like to combine multiple interfaces by declaring a custom `typealias`:

```
// This doesn't work
typealias MyType = (ReadableInterface && WritableInterface)
```

Any ideas?

---

In **Swift**, I would do it this way:

```
typealias MyType = ReadableInterface & WritableInterface
```

---

In **Objective C**, I would do it this way:

```
typedef <ReadableInterface, WritableInterface> MyType;
```

Comment: [You can not explicitly define intersection types in Kotlin, but you can use generic type constraints to achieve it in a function parameter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54847719/10536125)

Comment: Thank you @Bananon - any ideas how to apply this to `typealias`? Just wondering if a generic typealias actually make sense..

Comment: I think it's impossible to apply this to `typealias` in a current version of a language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just create new interface?

```
interface MyType : ReadableInterface, WritableInterface
```

Comment: Because you have to modify now all classes that would in other languages just mach without that...    I don't get this limitation of koltin ... sure swift has others and a lot but this is eve worst then Java , I needed to define constructor with multiple types and cannot do that cleanly in koltin anf polution my code with another another interface is not nice solution for me.

Comment: @Renetik why not define multiple constructors? Also, I don't get what `all classes` need to be changed?

Comment: Also, see this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847661/does-kotlin-support-or-have-future-plan-for-interface-composition-similar-to-pro/54847719#54847719

Comment: @Mick You were looking for Kotlin `typealias` solution but got content with rusty conventional answer that has nothing to do with `typealias`es?