# Pass a list of functions with different parameters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that calls functions depending on events. Events are emitted from sockets. I should catch these events, parse JSON and respond (call a corresponding function). For instance, `{"event_name": "message", "data": {"text": "dfgfdgfdg", "sender": "dsfdsfs"}}`

```
fun listener(jsonString: String, methodsMap: Map<String, () -> Unit>) {
    val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
    val data = json.getJSONObject("data")
    when (json.get("event_name")) {
        "update" -> {
            val count = data.getInt("count")
            methodsMap["update"]?.invoke(count) // 1 parameter.
        }
        "message" -> {
            val message = data.getString("text")
            val sender = data.getString("sender")
            methodsMap["message"]?.invoke(message, sender) // 2 parameters.
        }
    }
}
```

So, I cannot create one method that calls functions with different parameters. How to do this?

Comment: If the type of your functions is `() -> Unit` why do you invoke them with parameters?

Comment: @DavidSoroko, that was an example.

Comment: "functions with different parameters" means different amount of parameters and different type? or just an amount.

Comment: @BenShmuel, all functions may have different amount and type of parameters. For instance, the third function will have `Int`, `Int`, the fourth - `String`, `Int`, `String`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I wanted to use a `list` of parameters in each function, but it leads to poor type verification during compilation. Also I wanted to assign `vararg` instead of `List`, but couldn't.

```
fun listener(jsonString: String, methodsMap: Map<String, (List<Any>) -> Unit>) {
    ...
    methodsMap["update"]?.invoke(listOf(count)) // 1 parameter.
    ...
    methodsMap["message"]?.invoke(listOf(message, sender)) // 2 parameters.
}
```

This is a poor solution. Bugs may occur, we should remember to change `methodsMap` in every class that uses `listener` when we change any event.

Second, I tried to use `sealed classes`. This is not so simple.

Third, I tried to use `interface`. We know that callbacks are usually made with interfaces. We can even [merge interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044121/typealias-combine-multiple-interfaces-in-kotlin) in Kotlin. So, this can be a solution to a problem (but not to a question).

```
fun listener(jsonString: String, callback: EventListener) {
    val json = JSONObject(jsonString)
    val data = json.getJSONObject("data")
    when (json.get("event_name")) {
        "update" -> {
            val count = data.getInt("count")
            callback.onUpdate(count)
        }
        "message" -> {
            val text = data.getString("text")
            val sender = data.getString("sender")
            callback.onNewMessage(text, sender)
        }
    }
}

interface EventListener {
    fun onUpdate(count: Int)
    fun onNewMessage(text: String, sender: String)
}
```

Then we can call `listener` outside of the class and pass any callbacks we like.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already have **if-then** logic in `listener`, having the functions in a `Map` is of questionable value and it forces you to to deal with the fact that your functions are of different types. If it is parametrisation of `listener` you are after, perhaps this (simplified example code that skips JSON) is sufficient:

```kotlin
class UpdateHandler {
    fun update(n: Int) = println("update ( $n )")
}
class MessageHandler {
    fun message(s1: String, s2: String) = println("message ( $s1 $s2 )")
}

fun listener(jsonString: String, updateF: (Int) -> Unit, messageF: (String, String) -> Unit) {
    when (jsonString) {
        "update" -> updateF(73)
        "message" -> messageF("message", "sender")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val updateHandler = UpdateHandler()
    val messageHandler = MessageHandler()

    val listener = { json: String -> listener(json, updateHandler::update, messageHandler::message) }
    listener("update") // prints: update ( 73 )
    listener("message")// prints: message ( message sender )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good variant, but `listener` parameters may change when we add or edit events. So, every adding a new event will lead to changes in `listener`. I want to have single collection of functions, that should be changed outside of `listener`.

Comment: Even with all functions in a single map, you will need to change the `listener` code when you add/remove functions, since you are parsing the parameters before specific function invocation. I guess you could have several maps (by function type) , something like `processIntMap` and `processMessageMap`. This may or may not make sense in the context of your application

Comment: A good variant. A problem is I want to have public class with `listener` that will change if events change. And functions won't belong to that class, they should be passed to the `listener` method from other classes. So, they shouldn't be written near `listener`, but exist only in other classes. That's why I want to call `listener` and pass a list of methods to it. All JSON parsing logic should stay inside `listener`. I want to pass only callbacks.

Comment: I updated my answer so that "they shouldn't be written near listener, but exist only in other classes." . Fundamentally though, this is the same answer as before