# Is it possible in Kotlin to define a value with a combination of interfaces as type?

Tags: kotlin, types, interface

Say I have two Kotlin interfaces, like

```kotlin
interface MyInterfaceA {
  fun myFunA()
}
interface MyInterfaceB {
  fun myFunB()
}
```

Can I declare a value with type constrained to both interfaces at the same time? I.e., I am looking for something like this (pseudocode)

```kotlin
val myVal : {MyInterfaceA, MyInterfaceB} = ...
```

So that whatever I initialize `myVal` with must implement both interfaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54847719/12191177

Comment: You would need to define a third interface, which combines the two. Something like: _interface MyInterfaceA_B: MyInterfaceA, MyInterfaceB_, and then use that to type _myVal_.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could do,is to create another class or interface that implements both interfaces

```
  class CombineAB: MyInterfaceA, MyInterfaceB {

   }
   val myVal: CombineAB = ......
```